# How do I budget with cash surplus spending in mind?

Tags: small-business, budget, cash

I'm setting up a budget for my small business. We have been accumulating cash, but have not been budgeting up to this point, so are trying to get everything in order.

I've created a conservative budget based on last month's revenue numbers and accounted for all expenses, salaries, etc.

My question is this: How do we budget for spending some of the cash on large one-time reinvestments into the business?

For instance, given this example budget:

## May 2021 Budget

### Projected Income: $20,000

### Projected COGS: $9,000 (45%)

### Expenses: $10,000 (50%)

1. Wages: $8,000
2. Contractors: $400
3. Fees: $400
4. Software: $400
5. Supplies: $400
6. Legal & Professional: $200
7. Meals: $50
8. Maintenance: $50
9. Advertising: $50
10. Miscellaneous: $50

#### Net Income: $1,000 (5%)

---

How would I account for a **$5,000** one-time contractor expense for a new website? It will be paid from cash reserves, so it obviously would break this budget to include without including another revenue source.

I hope that makes sense, and thanks in advance for any help/direction you can offer!

Comment: Can you explain why you don't think it should be listed as an expense on the budget for May?

Comment: @HartCO Sorry, yes I think it would be an expense, but how would I denote the corresponding cash used to pay for it?

Comment: You'd just have negative net income on your budget for the month if your expenses exceed revenue. As for the accounting it could be as simple as credit cash account, credit expense account. Though do note that some parts of web development can be capitalized. A budget is just a plan for revenue/expenses, an income statement would show the actual revenue/expenses. Neither shows the state of cash-reserves and that's fine. A balance sheet shows that. Different purposes for each report type.

Comment: This question is about accounting, not personal finance.

Comment: @chepner sorry. Since the site is called "personal finance & money", I thought general questions about money fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few different ways you can do this:

- make your "net income" for that period negative and account for the actual cash balances elsewhere. This would ensure that cumulative
  "net income" is correct.
- include a "revenue" (or more appropriately "inflow") item called "cash from reserves" or something. That would account for the money you pulled out of what you've saved for this expense. If you don't have the money in savings, how do you intend to pay it? If you intend to borrow the money, include that as in "inflow". **If you do this**, your "bottom line" would no longer be "net income" but rather should zero out, and "net income" would then be a cash outflow to "net reserves". This would be the right "zero-based" budgeting technique.
- separate inflow/outflow accounting from balance accounting.

For more mature businesses, the financial statements have both statements of income (where income can be positive or negative) and a separate "balance sheet" where assets, liabilities, and equity (accumulated income plus whatever money was put into the business) must balance. That's a bit more complicated since you don't simply have revenues and expenses anymore - you need to keep track of where the money for expenses come from and where the money from revenue goes. But it's the next step from a pure inflow/outflow budget.

Comment: You can't pretend that cash reserves are additional cash coming into the company.

Comment: @HartCO That's not what I'm saying - I'm saying if your "budget" is just measuring inflows and outflows, then you can pull cash from reserves as an "inflow". Either that or have a "negative" net income and account for the actual cash balances elsewhere.

Comment: That's fair, if this is just an informal budget then it might be of no consequence. I'm accustomed to budgets being used in the context of income statements where a contrived 'inflow' would be inappropriate.

Comment: @HartCO Thinking about it more, maybe it is inappropriate if the bottom line is "net income", since it would skew the "total" income if all months were added together. In that case having a negative "net income" would be more appropriate.